# How do I make it so I can call an embed to another file and post it as such?

Tags: arguments, command, discord.js, embed

This is my index.js: (bot > index) The index is the main file. It's not the main focus of what I'm asking, but maybe the error could stem from here.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const prefix = "$";
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("This bot is online!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }

  // Destructure the first word from message.content, leave the rest as an array
  const [commandName, ...args] = message.content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .split(/ +/);


  const command = client.commands.get(commandName.toLowerCase());

  if (!command) {
    return; // do something
  }

  command.execute(message, args);
});

client.login("token")
```

;

This is my effect.js: (bot > commands > effect) This is where error codes are usually from. This is more of a command subfolder specifically for Pokemon effects. This specifically gives me the hardest for my goal because I don't know how to send code into another file while also not cramping it. My goal is simply: make the embed message without code junk.

```
//REMINDER: PREFIX IS $
  //RESET BOT TERMINAL CODE: NODE .

module.exports = {
  name: "effect",
  description: "Information on Pokemon!",
  execute(message, args) {
    // args[0] would be the second word from message.content
    // You should check if they used the command the right way
    // $effect some-type would make args[0] some-type
    var command = args[0]
    var channel = 0x792853588388872202

//POKEMON TYPE -- FAIRY
    if(command === 'fairy'){
      message.channel.send({embed: fairyEmbed});
      }
//POKEMON TYPE -- FIGHTING
    if(command === 'fighting'){
      channel.send(fightingEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- STEEL
    if(command === 'steel'){
      channel.send(steelEmbed);
      }
//POKEMON TYPE -- DARK
    if(command === 'dark'){
      channel.send(darkEmbed);
      }
//POKEMON TYPE -- DRAGON
    if(command === 'dragon'){
      channel.send(dragonEmbed);
      }
//POKEMON TYPE -- GHOST
    if(command === 'ghost'){
      channel.send(ghostEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- PSYCHIC
    if(command === 'psychic'){
     channel.send(psychicEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- ROCK
    if(command === 'rock'){
      channel.send(rockEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- BUG
    if(command === 'bug'){
      channel.send(bugEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- FLYING
    if(command === 'flying'){
      channel.send(flyingEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- GROUND
    if(command === 'ground'){
      channel.send(groundEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- POISON
    if(command === 'poison'){
      channel.send(poisonEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- ICE
    if(command === 'ice'){
      channel.send(ice);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- GRASS
    if(command === 'grass'){
      channel.send(grassEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- ELECTRIC
    if(command === 'electric'){
      channel.send(electricEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- WATER
    if(command === 'water'){
      channel.send(waterEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- FIRE
    if(command === 'fire'){
      channel.send(fireEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- NORMAL
    if(command === 'normal'){
      channel.send(normalEmbed);
    }
//POKEMON TYPE -- ALL
    if(command === 'all'){
      channel.send(allEmbed);
    }
  },
};
```

This is my effect-embed.js: (same as effect.js) Aka problem #2. This is where the embeds themselves are held. I have NO idea how to transfer them without copying and pasting so here I am.

```
// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const fairyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#dd525d')
    .setTitle('Fairy')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/0K6qBmnRizU')
    .setDescription('Fairy types are too cutesy for my preference. They’re weak to Poison and Steel type and Fire, Steel and Poison types resist their attacks. But they do a lot of damage to Dark, Fighting and Dragon types. Dragon type attacks don’t effect them at all, so they’re good in that department.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F627055948095995745%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Vu5xwOk0k9tBEJ9Yclz2F&ust=1609622152653000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCICQ3vXT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')
message.channel.send({embed: fairyEmbed});

const fightingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#61dde6')
    .setTitle('Fighting')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/FJgRlbjzsrs')
    .setDescription('Fighting types are very resilient. Their attacks are super effective against Rock, Steel, Dark, Normal and Ice types and they resist Dark, Rock and Bug type attacks. Fighting type attacks won’t do well against Flying, Psychic, Fairy, Poison or Bug types and they won’t do anything to Ghost types and they’re very weak to Fairy, Psychic and Flying type attacks.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpokemon.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FZamazenta_(anime)&psig=AOvVaw1b8V8kCknIyef2c_zxuFjV&ust=1609622421791000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJCsvPXU--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAM')

const steelEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ba2838')
    .setTitle('Steel')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/I_57ptO3TKc')
    .setDescription('Steel types are the prime definition of defense with an amazing resistance to Normal, Grass, Ice, Flying, Psychic, Bug, Rock, Dragon, Steel and Fairy type attacks and are immune to Poison attacks. They’ll do immense damage to Rock, Fairy and Ice types. If they get hit by Fire, Ground or Fighting type attacks, they’ll be greatly damaged and they don’t do much to Water, Fire, Electric or other Steel types.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpokemongohub.net%2Fpost%2Fguide%2Fdialga-heat-map%2F&psig=AOvVaw3l68mb5ltZZZusGgHSGLTd&ust=1609622768057000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKjLpZ_W--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAV')

const darkEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#3a4c7b')
    .setTitle('Dark')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/0K6qBmnRizU')
    .setDescription('Dark type Pokémon are masters of the night and dirty, underhanded tactics. They’re very strong against Psychic and Ghost and resist Dark and Ghost type attacks. Psychic type attacks don’t stand a chance due to their immunity. It’s best to avoid putting them against Fighting, Fairy and Bug type attacks because of their weakness and they won’t do as much damage against Dark, Fighting and Fairy type Pokémon. Either way you slice it, Dark type Pokémon are very strong. Spikemuth’s gym is a prime example of that.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbulbapedia.bulbagarden.net%2Fwiki%2FYveltal_(Pok%25C3%25A9mon)&psig=AOvVaw01HxoY93uTikkUD-yDrdJU&ust=1609623455517000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIDG2OLY--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')

const dragonEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#352822')
    .setTitle('Dragon')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/8lrMjcNJGfE')
    .setDescription('Dragon types are very rare and thought to be a mystical type. If you want to stop them in their tracks, use Fairy, Ice or Dragon type moves against them. Dragon types resist Fire, Water, Grass and Electric type attacks and Dragon Type attacks are only strong against themselves but have a wide variety of attacks. Dragons type moves don’t do much to Steel types and Fairy types are completely immune to their attacks. My bro said Raihan was infamous for completely demolishing trainers with his overwhelming dragons, so I’d watch your choices around them.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbleedingcool.com%2Fgames%2Frayquaza-raid-guide-how-to-catch-a-shiny-rayquaza-in-pokemon-go%2F&psig=AOvVaw02L1u59NkP3kqQSp5xAJKB&ust=1609623775222000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIiX9PvZ--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')

const ghostEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#352822')
    .setTitle('Dragon')
    .setURL('https://youtu.be/8lrMjcNJGfE')
    .setDescription('Dragon types are very rare and thought to be a mystical type. If you want to stop them in their tracks, use Fairy, Ice or Dragon type moves against them. Dragon types resist Fire, Water, Grass and Electric type attacks and Dragon Type attacks are only strong against themselves but have a wide variety of attacks. Dragons type moves don’t do much to Steel types and Fairy types are completely immune to their attacks. My bro said Raihan was infamous for completely demolishing trainers with his overwhelming dragons, so I’d watch your choices around them.')
    .setThumbnail('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zedge.net%2Fwallpaper%2F23b8d5ed-9f57-39e7-b27c-ffd2df026702&psig=AOvVaw3xIwv-YzXf8AuUEaTGfBp4&ust=1609622014464000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDrk7TT--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ')
    .setImage('https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbleedingcool.com%2Fgames%2Frayquaza-raid-guide-how-to-catch-a-shiny-rayquaza-in-pokemon-go%2F&psig=AOvVaw02L1u59NkP3kqQSp5xAJKB&ust=1609623775222000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIiX9PvZ--0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to module.exports every embed. I'll give you an example:

```
module.exports = darkEmbed;
```

And then you're going to import darkEmbed in your other file.

```
const { darkEmbed } = require("file")
```

The { } are there because you have more then one object in the embeds file.

Comment: I did that but whenever I entered the file name including the "./" I get an error saying module is not found. I tried googling the error but all that showed up was the directory was wrong, however I checked multiple times and I know I haven't. Then it says that I need to install it or something? I guess save it to another place. I did that too, yet nothing happens.

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) package then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `module.exports` in your `effect-embeds.js` file, and require it in your `effect.js` file.

E.g.

```js
// effect-embeds.js

module.exports.effect = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    //embed information

// Compared to (DO NOT DO)
const effect = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    //embed information
```

Then in your other file...

```js
// effect.js 
const { effect } = require("./effect.embeds.js"); // Change the file import based on where it is located

channel.send(effect);
```

Also, instead of using `if` statements over and over

```js
if(...) {
  //code
}
```

Use a `switch`.

```js
switch(command) {
   case '...':
      // code
   break;
}
```